Error: export 'ɵɵInputFlags' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core' angular 18
Migration from angular 17 => 18.
Getting this error in @ng-bootstrap and I have the last version of this dependencies:
./node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/fesm2022/ng-bootstrap.mjs:1896:13-33 - Error: export 'ɵɵInputFlags' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core' (possible exports: ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE, APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER, APP_ID, APP_INITIALIZER, AfterRenderPhase, ApplicationInitStatus, ApplicationModule, ApplicationRef, Attribute, COMPILER_OPTIONS, CSP_NONCE, CUSTOM_ELEM ...........

ng-bootstrap version:
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "16.0.0",

And same problem with ngx-bootstrap:
./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/tooltip/fesm2022/ngx-bootstrap-tooltip.mjs:380:26-46 - Error: export 'ɵɵInputFlags' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core' (possible exports: ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE, APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER, APP_ID, APP_INITIALIZER, AfterRenderPhase, ApplicationInitStatus, ApplicationModule, ApplicationRef, Attribute, COMPILER_OPTIONS, CSP_NONCE, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, Compiler, CompilerFactory, Component, ComponentFactory, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef, ContentChild, ContentChildren, DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE, DebugElement, DebugEventListener, DebugNode, DefaultIterableDiffer, DestroyRef, Directive, ENVIRONMENT_INITIALIZER, ElementRef, EmbeddedViewRef, EnvironmentInjector, ErrorHandler, EventEmitter, ExperimentalPendingTasks, HOST_TAG_NAME, Host, HostAttributeToken, HostBinding, HostListener, INJECTOR, Inject, InjectFlags, Injectable, InjectionToken, Injector, Input, IterableDiffers, KeyValueDiffers, LOCALE_ID, MissingTranslationStrategy, ModuleWithComponentFactories, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, NgModule, NgModuleFactory, NgModuleRef, NgProbeToken, NgZone, Optional, Output, OutputEmitterRef, PACKAGE_ROOT_URL, PLATFORM_ID, PLATFORM_INITIALIZER, Pipe, PlatformRef, Query, QueryList, Renderer2, RendererFactory2, RendererStyleFlags2, Sanitizer, SecurityContext, Self, SimpleChange, SkipSelf, TRANSLATIONS, TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, TemplateRef, Testability, TestabilityRegistry, TransferState, Type, VERSION, Version, ViewChild, ViewChildren, ViewContainerRef, ViewEncapsulation, ViewRef, afterNextRender, afterRender, asNativeElements, assertInInjectionContext, assertNotInReactiveContext, assertPlatform, booleanAttribute, computed, contentChild, contentChildren, createComponent, createEnvironmentInjector, createNgModule, createNgModuleRef, createPlatform, createPlatformFactory, defineInjectable, destroyPlatform, effect, enableProdMode, forwardRef, getDebugNode, getModuleFactory, getNgModuleById, getPlatform, importProvidersFrom, inject, input, isDevMode, isSignal, isStandalone, makeEnvironmentProviders, makeStateKey, mergeApplicationConfig, model, numberAttribute, output, platformCore, provideExperimentalCheckNoChangesForDebug, provideExperimentalZonelessChangeDetection, provideZoneChangeDetection, reflectComponentType, resolveForwardRef, runInInjectionContext, setTestabilityGetter, signal, untracked, viewChild, viewChildren, ɵALLOW_MULTIPLE_PLATFORMS, ɵAfterRenderEventManager, 
ɵCONTAINER_HEADER_OFFSET, ɵChangeDetectionScheduler, ɵChangeDetectionSchedulerImpl, ɵComponentFactory, ɵConsole, ɵDEFAULT_LOCALE_ID, ɵDEFER_BLOCK_CONFIG, ɵDEFER_BLOCK_DEPENDENCY_INTERCEPTOR, ɵDeferBlockBehavior, ɵDeferBlockState, ɵEffectScheduler, ɵIMAGE_CONFIG, ɵIMAGE_CONFIG_DEFAULTS, ɵINJECTOR_SCOPE, ɵINPUT_SIGNAL_BRAND_WRITE_TYPE, ɵIS_HYDRATION_DOM_REUSE_ENABLED, ɵLContext, 
ɵLifecycleHooksFeature, ɵLocaleDataIndex, ɵNG_COMP_DEF, ɵNG_DIR_DEF, ɵNG_ELEMENT_ID, ɵNG_INJ_DEF, ɵNG_MOD_DEF, ɵNG_PIPE_DEF, ɵNG_PROV_DEF, ɵNOT_FOUND_CHECK_ONLY_ELEMENT_INJECTOR, ɵNO_CHANGE, ɵNgModuleFactory, ɵNoopNgZone, ɵPendingTasks, ɵReflectionCapabilities, ɵRender3ComponentFactory, ɵRender3ComponentRef, ɵRender3NgModuleRef, ɵRuntimeError, ɵSSR_CONTENT_INTEGRITY_MARKER, ɵTESTABILITY, ɵTESTABILITY_GETTER, ɵUSE_RUNTIME_DEPS_TRACKER_FOR_JIT, ɵViewRef, ɵXSS_SECURITY_URL, ɵZONELESS_ENABLED, ɵ_sanitizeHtml, ɵ_sanitizeUrl, ɵallowSanitizationBypassAndThrow, ɵannotateForHydration, ɵbypassSanitizationTrustHtml, ɵbypassSanitizationTrustResourceUrl, ɵbypassSanitizationTrustScript, ɵbypassSanitizationTrustStyle, ɵbypassSanitizationTrustUrl, ɵclearResolutionOfComponentResourcesQueue, ɵcompileComponent, ɵcompileDirective, ɵcompileNgModule, ɵcompileNgModuleDefs, ɵcompileNgModuleFactory, ɵcompilePipe, ɵconvertToBitFlags, ɵcreateInjector, ɵdefaultIterableDiffers, ɵdefaultKeyValueDiffers, ɵdepsTracker, ɵdetectChangesInViewIfRequired, ɵdevModeEqual, ɵfindLocaleData, ɵflushModuleScopingQueueAsMuchAsPossible, ɵformatRuntimeError, ɵgenerateStandaloneInDeclarationsError, ɵgetAsyncClassMetadataFn, ɵgetDebugNode, ɵgetDeferBlocks, ɵgetDirectives, ɵgetHostElement, ɵgetInjectableDef, ɵgetLContext, ɵgetLocaleCurrencyCode, ɵgetLocalePluralCase, ɵgetOutputDestroyRef, ɵgetSanitizationBypassType, ɵgetUnknownElementStrictMode, ɵgetUnknownPropertyStrictMode, ɵglobal, ɵinjectChangeDetectorRef, ɵinternalAfterNextRender, ɵinternalCreateApplication, ɵinternalProvideZoneChangeDetection, ɵisBoundToModule, ɵisComponentDefPendingResolution, ɵisEnvironmentProviders, ɵisInjectable, ɵisNgModule, ɵisPromise, ɵisSubscribable, ɵnoSideEffects, ɵpatchComponentDefWithScope, ɵperformanceMarkFeature, ɵqueueStateUpdate, ɵreadHydrationInfo, ɵregisterLocaleData, ɵrenderDeferBlockState, ɵresetCompiledComponents, ɵresetJitOptions, ɵresolveComponentResources, ɵrestoreComponentResolutionQueue, ɵsetAllowDuplicateNgModuleIdsForTest, ɵsetAlternateWeakRefImpl, ɵsetClassDebugInfo, ɵsetClassMetadata, ɵsetClassMetadataAsync, ɵsetCurrentInjector, ɵsetDocument, ɵsetInjectorProfilerContext, ɵsetLocaleId, ɵsetUnknownElementStrictMode, ɵsetUnknownPropertyStrictMode, ɵstore, ɵstringify, ɵtransitiveScopesFor, ɵtriggerResourceLoading, ɵtruncateMiddle, ɵunregisterLocaleData, ɵunwrapSafeValue, ɵunwrapWritableSignal, ɵwhenStable, ɵwithDomHydration, ɵwithEventReplay, ɵwithI18nSupport, ɵɵCopyDefinitionFeature, ɵɵFactoryTarget, ɵɵHostDirectivesFeature, ɵɵInheritDefinitionFeature, ɵɵInputTransformsFeature, ɵɵNgOnChangesFeature, ɵɵProvidersFeature, ɵɵStandaloneFeature, ɵɵadvance, ɵɵattribute, ɵɵattributeInterpolate1, ɵɵattributeInterpolate2, ɵɵattributeInterpolate3, ɵɵattributeInterpolate4, ɵɵattributeInterpolate5, ɵɵattributeInterpolate6, ɵɵattributeInterpolate7, ɵɵattributeInterpolate8, ɵɵattributeInterpolateV, ɵɵclassMap, ɵɵclassMapInterpolate1, ɵɵclassMapInterpolate2, ɵɵclassMapInterpolate3, ɵɵclassMapInterpolate4, ɵɵclassMapInterpolate5, ɵɵclassMapInterpolate6, ɵɵclassMapInterpolate7, ɵɵclassMapInterpolate8, ɵɵclassMapInterpolateV, ɵɵclassProp, ɵɵcomponentInstance, ɵɵconditional, ɵɵcontentQuery, ɵɵcontentQuerySignal, ɵɵdefer, ɵɵdeferEnableTimerScheduling, ɵɵdeferOnHover, ɵɵdeferOnIdle, ɵɵdeferOnImmediate, ɵɵdeferOnInteraction, ɵɵdeferOnTimer, ɵɵdeferOnViewport, ɵɵdeferPrefetchOnHover, ɵɵdeferPrefetchOnIdle, ɵɵdeferPrefetchOnImmediate, ɵɵdeferPrefetchOnInteraction, ɵɵdeferPrefetchOnTimer, ɵɵdeferPrefetchOnViewport, ɵɵdeferPrefetchWhen, ɵɵdeferWhen, ɵɵdefineComponent, ɵɵdefineDirective, ɵɵdefineInjectable, ɵɵdefineInjector, ɵɵdefineNgModule, ɵɵdefinePipe, ɵɵdirectiveInject, ɵɵdisableBindings, ɵɵelement, ɵɵelementContainer, ɵɵelementContainerEnd, ɵɵelementContainerStart, ɵɵelementEnd, ɵɵelementStart, ɵɵenableBindings, ɵɵgetComponentDepsFactory, ɵɵgetCurrentView, ɵɵgetInheritedFactory, ɵɵhostProperty, ɵɵi18n, ɵɵi18nApply, ɵɵi18nAttributes, ɵɵi18nEnd, ɵɵi18nExp, ɵɵi18nPostprocess, ɵɵi18nStart, ɵɵinject, ɵɵinjectAttribute, ɵɵinvalidFactory, ɵɵinvalidFactoryDep, ɵɵlistener, ɵɵloadQuery, ɵɵnamespaceHTML, ɵɵnamespaceMathML, ɵɵnamespaceSVG, ɵɵnextContext, ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata, ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadataAsync, ɵɵngDeclareComponent, ɵɵngDeclareDirective, ɵɵngDeclareFactory, ɵɵngDeclareInjectable, ɵɵngDeclareInjector, ɵɵngDeclareNgModule, ɵɵngDeclarePipe, ɵɵpipe, ɵɵpipeBind1, ɵɵpipeBind2, ɵɵpipeBind3, ɵɵpipeBind4, ɵɵpipeBindV, ɵɵprojection, ɵɵprojectionDef, ɵɵproperty, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate1, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate2, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate3, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate4, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate5, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate6, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate7, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate8, ɵɵpropertyInterpolateV, ɵɵpureFunction0, ɵɵpureFunction1, ɵɵpureFunction2, ɵɵpureFunction3, ɵɵpureFunction4, ɵɵpureFunction5, ɵɵpureFunction6, ɵɵpureFunction7, ɵɵpureFunction8, ɵɵpureFunctionV, ɵɵqueryAdvance, ɵɵqueryRefresh, ɵɵreference, ɵɵregisterNgModuleType, ɵɵrepeater, ɵɵrepeaterCreate, ɵɵrepeaterTrackByIdentity, ɵɵrepeaterTrackByIndex, ɵɵresetView, ɵɵresolveBody, ɵɵresolveDocument, ɵɵresolveWindow, ɵɵrestoreView, ɵɵsanitizeHtml, ɵɵsanitizeResourceUrl, ɵɵsanitizeScript, ɵɵsanitizeStyle, ɵɵsanitizeUrl, ɵɵsanitizeUrlOrResourceUrl, ɵɵsetComponentScope, ɵɵsetNgModuleScope, ɵɵstyleMap, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolate1, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolate2, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolate3, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolate4, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolate5, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolate6, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolate7, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolate8, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolateV, ɵɵstyleProp, ɵɵstylePropInterpolate1, ɵɵstylePropInterpolate2, ɵɵstylePropInterpolate3, ɵɵstylePropInterpolate4, ɵɵstylePropInterpolate5, ɵɵstylePropInterpolate6, ɵɵstylePropInterpolate7, ɵɵstylePropInterpolate8, ɵɵstylePropInterpolateV, ɵɵsyntheticHostListener, ɵɵsyntheticHostProperty, ɵɵtemplate, ɵɵtemplateRefExtractor, ɵɵtext, ɵɵtextInterpolate, ɵɵtextInterpolate1, ɵɵtextInterpolate2, ɵɵtextInterpolate3, ɵɵtextInterpolate4, ɵɵtextInterpolate5, ɵɵtextInterpolate6, ɵɵtextInterpolate7, ɵɵtextInterpolate8, ɵɵtextInterpolateV, ɵɵtrustConstantHtml, ɵɵtrustConstantResourceUrl, ɵɵtwoWayBindingSet, ɵɵtwoWayListener, ɵɵtwoWayProperty, ɵɵvalidateIframeAttribute, ɵɵviewQuery, ɵɵviewQuerySignal)

ngx-bootstrap version :
"ngx-bootstrap": "12.0.0",


ng-boostrap is likely not compatible yet : https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/4703

Please also mention your exact angular dependencies version
